# how can i handle my custom event in style->eventsetter?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, user-controls, eventsetter

I have made a custom event handler in my usercontrol:

```
public partial class FooControl
{
   public event RoutedEventHandler AddFoo;

   private void AddFoo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (AddFoo != null)
           AddFoo(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
   }
}
```

when I want to handle the event like this, everything works fine:

```
<controls:FooControl AddFoo="FooControl_OnAddFoo"/>
```

I wanted to do it like that but then something crashes and I don't know why.

```
<Style TargetType="controls:FooControl">
    <EventSetter Event="AddFoo" Handler="Event_AddFoo"/>
</Style>
```

Further information:
the editor underlines AddFoo in the EventSetter and says

- the event "AddFoo" is not a routed event
- routed event descriptor field "AddFooEvent" missing
- throws an exception: Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
- inner exception says value must not be null

**EDIT:**

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent AddEvent = 
                               EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent
                               ("AddEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
                               typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(FooControl));
public event RoutedEventHandler AddFoo
{
    add { AddHandler(AddEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(AddEvent, value); }
}

void RaiseAddEvent()
{
    RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(FooControl.AddEvent);
    RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
}

private void AddFoo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RaiseAddEvent();
}
```

Comment: `EventSetter` supports only routed events. Your event is a plain-old CLR event. You can convert your `AddFoo` event to a routed event.

Comment: thanks for the quick response but can you tell me how I convert it and why my AddFoo is not a routed event?

Comment: Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event) how to define a custom routed event.

Comment: already read that and tried it like above in the edit. It's still not working... can you see any mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event needs to be a routed event.

According to your code, the routed event registration is incorrect.

Here is the right one:

```
// 'AddEvent' is the name of the property that holds the routed event ID 
public static readonly RoutedEvent AddEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent
    ("Add", // the event name is 'Add'
    RoutingStrategy.Bubble, 
    typeof(RoutedEventHandler),
    typeof(FooControl));

// The event name is 'Add'
public event RoutedEventHandler Add
{
    add { AddHandler(AddEvent, value); }
    remove { RemoveHandler(AddEvent, value); }
}
```

Please pay attention to the event name. Don't confuse it with the event ID property. This is important.

Comment: oh ok so i am registering the handler not the event itself? but now it works... thank you very much

Comment: No, you're not registering any event. Your registration code is incorrect. You're getting exceptions because WPF cannot find a routed event with the name you specify.

Comment: Yeah I got that with my registration code but `RegisterRoutedEvent ("Add"...` is registering the name of this event isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's right. This is the event name. It has to be the same as the CLR event (that one with `add` and `remove` accessors).